# Is there any way to merge Sprites as Geometries in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, sprite

In my case, I want to put some labels with the name of some cities over a terrain. But when I put more than ten, the fps decrease a lot.

I've followed the written code here http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html

My code is something like that:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var sizeCanvas = 250;
canvas.width = sizeCanvas;
canvas.height = sizeCanvas;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.font = "Bold " + size + "px " + font;
context.textAlign = 'center';

contexto.fillStyle = "rgba(10, 10, 10, 1.0)";

contexto.fillText(text, sizeCanvas / 2, sizeCanvas / 2);

var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
texture.needsUpdate = true;

var labelMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial(
        {map: texture, useScreenCoordinates: false});
var label = new THREE.Sprite(labelMaterial);

label.position.x = this._vector.x;
label.position.y = this._vector.y;
label.position.z = this._vector.z;

etiqueta.scale.set(10, 10, 1.0);

scene.add(label);
```

I supose that the main trouble to merge the sprites is for the diferent texture for every label.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Do you want the labels of you cities to be always facing the camera?

Comment: Then you cannot really merge all your sprites into one. One big sprite faces the camera differently than separate small ones do.

Comment: I imagined that. Thanks.

Comment: "But when I put more than ten, the fps decrease a lot." That should not be happening. Can you show a live example?

Comment: I am sorry but the aplication is hosted in a local server and I need some java servlet calls to get the cities. I share the difference in photos http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=i2rq50&s=8#.U3-dYPmB06g http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2pqjgo6&s=8#.U3-dtPmB06g

Comment: Ok, finally I found the trouble, simply when I updated the labels with a new city I deleted in the scene the old labels and I created again the same labels (yes, I created all the textures again). Now I storage  in a cache the cities already visited and I only create the actually new.

Answer (score 2):

For the ultimate performance boost (more work than what @raphaelRauwolf suggested, talking hundredthousands here) you'd have to use the ParticleSystem (Rendering with GL_POINT) together with a TextureAtlas you dynamically allocate with subimaging (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/4661) according to the camera's nearest neighbours (http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_nearestneighbour). For the other name plates which are not around the camera you can have a second TextureAtlas with smaller preview nameplates.

If you only have around 1'000 you can do the same without nearestneighbour and subimaging. Just create a TextureAtlas with all your nameplates and render them with the THREE.ParticleSystem :)

If you're interested in one of those two approaches, tell me, and I'll elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you create a canvas object for every label. What you can do is, you pass the Base64 encoded image from the canvas to the texture and write the next label into the same canvas. This should give you and performance boost. For example:

```
// create the canvas once
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

// set the size of the canvas
var sizeCanvas = 250;
canvas.width = sizeCanvas;
canvas.height = sizeCanvas;

// get the context and set the styles
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.font = "Bold " + size + "px " + font;
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillStyle = "rgba(10, 10, 10, 1.0)";

// iterate through your labels
for(var i = 0, j = myLabels.length; i < j; i++){
  contex.fillText(myLabels[i].text, sizeCanvas / 2, sizeCanvas / 2);

  // create the texture
  var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas.toDataURL());
  texture.needsUpdate = true; // don't know if this is needed

  // put the texture into the material
  var labelMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture, useScreenCoordinates: false});

  var label = new THREE.Sprite(labelMaterial);

  // set the label position to the vector, maybe you should put the vector into myLabels aswell
  label.position = this._vector.clone();

  // add the label to the scene
  scene.add(label);

  // clear the canvas for the new text
  context.clearRect(0,0,sizeCanvas,sizeCanvas);
}

etiqueta.scale.set(10, 10, 1.0);
```